# Can I protect Win7 system file by password

Tags: windows-7, windows, hosts-file, password-protection

I need to protect the `C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts` file by password. As I know any software can't protect a folder or a file within the Windows folder. Or is there still some way? Or can I move the hosts file out of the `Windows\System32\drivers\etc\` folders, protect it by password and change path to it in some file(s) of the Windows 7 system?

Comment: who are you protecting it from?  if they have admin privs, you cant prevent them from modifying it.

Comment: What is wrong with my question? Can downvoter explain?

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't [changing the ownership](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ff404240.aspx) of the file be a simpler method? Assign it to *Administrator* so that users cannot play with it. Even more extreme: assign it to *[trustedinstaller](http://www.askvg.com/guide-how-to-restore-trustedinstaller-as-default-owner-of-a-file-or-folder-in-windows/)*... rather a nuisance, but even better protected than *Administrator*.